# Don't let <video autoplay loop muted> pause when switched to background

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, autoplay

I want to use HTML5 video as a replacement to GIF since it has smaller file size. A GIF starts playing as soon as it's loaded and keeps looping all the time. So far `<video autoplay loop muted>` has been good, it behaves almost identical to a GIF.

But soon I found out, on Android Chrome, when the browser has been switched to background and back, the video will be paused. I don't want that, I want the video to keep playing and looping as a GIF does.

I know that WebKit based browsers need the video to be muted for them to autoplay, but it doesn't seem like to be the issue here.

I tried a dirty hack, which is adding `onpause="this.play()"` to the element. But it doesn't work in occassion. And it is hack that requires JS. So is there a better, or canonical way to do this?

Comment: why do you want to do something that most best practice says is a bad idea? having the video playing consumed bandwidth and (if it isn't muted) creates an audio source that's hard for the user to find and silence.

Comment: @Offbeatmammal I am using video as a replacement to GIF. It will not be large and will not have any audio. In fact videos of the same content have a lot smaller file size than GIFs.